# Ruby gem collection site

Tags: ruby, rubygems, toolbox

As I understand, Ruby Toolbox site has laid down for more than six months. It's really sad, but may there be any similar resource?

In rubygems, I cannot select the subject or the category of a gem; only little description is available.

I wrote a gem, and want to distribute it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout [Awesome Ruby](http://awesome-ruby.com/), it bills itself as:

> A categorized community-driven collection of awesome Ruby libraries, 
>   tools, frameworks and software. The essential Ruby to build modern Apps 
>   and Web Apps.

Though there's no guarantee that your gem will be added. Checkout their [contribution guidelines](https://github.com/markets/awesome-ruby/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md).

For similar lists for other languages checkout [the list of awesome lists](https://github.com/sindresorhus/awesome).

Comment: Following your answer, I just added that to the [Ruby tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ruby/info) page.

Comment: Awesome Ruby is OK but you can't really trust that what makes it there is actually awesome. I'd recommend looking at the github for any library you are thinking of using, see how active the development community is around it, how good the test suite is and of course actually look at the code, don't just trust blindly.

Comment: FWIW [Awsome Ruby's contrubition guidlines](https://github.com/markets/awesome-ruby/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#quality-standard) state that in order to stay on the list a project must be actively maintained and include tests -amongst other things...

Comment: It's really what I'm looked for. Thank you very mach for your time :)